# Server list Os type to CSV Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Quick question, I wanted to be able to pull a large list of server and spit the OS type with the server name into a CSV file. I have gotten this script to do that for the most part, however I am running into a few issues.

1. The script fails unless I have the columns already in the csv, I have a feeling im using the append flag incorrectly.
2. The list in question could contain Linux, Sun system, older then win 2003 and other non windows system. As a result error are going to happen, currently it just skips a line in the csv. Is there a way to write the server name and the word failed in the Os filed? Or just disable errors in general?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\Automation\Servers.txt 
Foreach ($s in $servers) 
    {   

        $OSInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $s #Get OS Information 

        $infoObject = New-Object PSObject 

        Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "ServerName" -value    $CPUInfo.SystemName 
        Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "OS_Name" -value $OSInfo.Caption

        $infoObject | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path C:\Automation\test.csv

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a try-catch you can more easily handle error situations, so I would start to examine the following changes to the code:

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\Automation\Servers.txt
$output = @()
foreach ($s in $servers)
    {
        $infoObject = New-Object PSObject

        try {
            $OSInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $s
            Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name 'ServerName' -value $s
            Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name 'OS_Name' -value $OSInfo.Caption
        }
        catch {
            Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name 'ServerName' -value $s
            Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name 'OS_Name' -value 'Non-Windows'
        }
        $output += $infoObject
    }
$output | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\Automation\test.csv
```

One of the changes here, besides the try-catch, is that I create an empty array, and collect all the infoObjects in this, and just do one export-csv in the end. That way you shouldn't get the problem with the csv. I also use the $s for servername so that you will get the servername even though the WMI query fails. You also get 'Non-Windows' for any server were WMI fails. You could perhaps change this to 'WMI Failed' or something if you want to, as it might also fail on windows servers of course.

NOTE! I haven't actually tested this code, but it should give you something to work on. There are other stuff you could look into to optimize it a bit as well, such as using a WMI -query, and there is also easier ways of creating a PSObject, but since yours just have two properties it won't matter as much.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Hey thanks! Awesome I will read more on try and catch, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` to make `Get-WmiObject` ignore errors. Also, the `-ComputerName` parameter accepts an array of hostnames, so you don't need to run the cmdlet in a loop and append to the output file multiple times.

```psh
$serverlist = 'C:\Automation\Servers.txt'
$oslist     = 'C:\Automation\test.csv'

$servers = Get-Content $serverlist

$ErrorActionPrefSave   = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$OSInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $servers |
          select @{n='Computer';e={$_.__SERVER}},
                 @{n='OS_Name';e={$_.Caption}}
$ErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPrefSave

# write responses to output file
$OSInfo | Export-Csv $oslist -NoType

# filter hosts that responded from server list and append the remaining hosts
# (the ones that did not respond) with a failure notice to the output file
$servers | ? { $OSInfo.Computer -notcontains $_ } |
  select @{n='Computer';e={$_}}, @{n='OS_Name';e={'connection failed'}} |
  Export-Csv $oslist -NoType -Append
```

Note that `$OSInfo.Computer -notcontains $_` requires PowerShell v3 or newer. For earlier PowerShell versions you need to change that to `($OSInfo | select -Expand Computer) -notcontains $_`.